Interchanging 〜たところだった and 〜たところだ
In what situations replacing 〜たところだった with 〜たところだ and vice versa does not change meaning?
Consider these sentences:

もう少しブレーキを踏むのが遅れていたら死んでいたところだった。(source)

やっと馴れてきたところだったのに、仕事を辞めなければいけなくなった。(source)


In 1, the only difference between 死んでいたところだった and 死んでいたところだ is that in the latter the observation point is now, and on the other hand, in the former, the observation point is in the past. But I don't think the meaning changes when using 〜たところだ instead of 〜たところだった?
In 2, I think whether it is acceptable to replace 〜たところだったのに with 〜たところなのに or not depends on how 仕事を辞めなければいけなくなった is understood. Without further context, なった is either in simple past form or in present perfect form. If なった is in simple past form, then it would be weird to use 〜たところなのに. But if なった is in present perfect form, I think it is acceptable?
Any thoughts?

This seems related.
